# Exploit execvp() with alias

Tags: c, linux, exec, alias, exploit

For a class assignment we must exploit a program and gain shell access. I have acess to the source and there is a line similar to

```
execvp("mkdir", "directory", null);
```

I am currently using a custom written c program to attempt to exploit the program. My sploit code is using execve(target, args, env) in order to start the target program. Im wondering if its possible to supply an 'alias mkdir="/bin/sh;"' to the execve call. If this was possible then when the execvp line runs it will execute /bin/sh instead of mkdir thus giving me a shell?

Ive tried supplying 'alias mkdir="/bin/sh;"' as an env variable but this did not work.

Everything runs in a virtual linux environment.

Comment: From what you have said a shell will be started and then it will exit. I think you want a terminal instead right?

Comment: im not entirely sure what the difference would be but we definitely need to run whats in /bin/sh. the only reason I thought the ';' is needed to stop the "directory" parameters from interfering with the parsing of the command. Ive tried removing the ';' and see no difference.

Comment: a shell is just a process. you actually want command line access to it right? could you be more specific about what the exact aim is? what is the burden of proof that you have to supply??

Comment: The burden of proof is when running my exploit, a command prompt is presented, and typing `whoami` results in 'root' being printed to the screen. Note that the program being exploited is marked to run as root, this is why executing /bin/sh would do the trick.

Comment: And the command prompt is in a terminal. Or are you planning to present it by some other means. Open a terminal. In isolation /bin/sh will start a process and processes can be started without a terminal being attached to them. Consider what happens when a process is started in cron, or as a daemon. Look at running a terminal and set one of the parameters to start shell /bin/sh. By way of a proof of concept run ' xterm -e "/bin/sh" ' at the command line and then try to get the exploited program to do the same thing. I think the shell might be selectable by direct use of a parameter.

Comment: While its an interesting topic, I'm not sure its a programming or development question. Maybe [Reverse Engineering Stack Exchange](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to discuss it.